# UNICODE-normailzed Korean Hangeul doesn't show up properly on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode

I'm working on an application for myself to help me study Korean in TKinter. To be sure that when I compare strings it is case insensitive, I use NFKD unicode normalization.

The unicode-normalized Korean letters appear well in the command line, but fail in TKinter pop-up messages and windows. It didn't seem to affect how the Hungarian unicode characters appear though.

If I don't use unicode normalization, just type the string, it appears well on TKinter.

```
print(list(szavak.keys()))
['앵무새', '참새', '개', '강아지', '고양이']

messagebox.showwarning(" ", ", ".join(list(szavak.keys())))
```

TKinter exploded Korean letters:

[image: TKinter exploded Korean letters]

```
messagebox.showwarning(" ", "앵무새, 참새, 개, 강아지, 고양이")
```

Tkinter nice Korean letters:

[image: TKinter nice Korean letters]

Is there any other way of normalizing the strings, where the case-insensitivity works in Roman (Greek, Cyrillic, etc.)-letters, but still provides a format that TKinter can handle?

Or is there any way to "un-normalize" the text for display purposes?

Comment: It may be that you need to use a font that supports these characters.

Comment: `NFKD` is _Compatibility **Decomposition**_.  For instance, `앵` _Hangul Syllable Ieung Ae Ieung_ is decomposed to `ᄋ` _Hangul Choseong Ieung_, `ᅢ` _Hangul Jungseong Ae_, and `ᆼ` _Hangul Jongseong Ieung_ Apply [`NFKC` or `NFC` normalization](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).